# Python, process animated gif preserving animation parameters

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, animated-gif, pythonmagick

Is that possible to process (expand, add background and some text "below" the original image) animated gif in Python?
I believe I should process each frame separately (which is a bit of performance issue, but still better than nothing) yet I can't find **any** working code at all.

PIL's support for animated gifs seems to be very limited

PythonMagick - well, maybe it supports but **no docs at all**

Wand - doesn't seem to support iterating through frames...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** (2013-06-18): Wand 0.3 now provides [sequence feature](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3-maintenance/guide/sequence.html) that you need.

There’s a [patch](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/pull/88) to fix it for Wand.  This will be eventually merged to upstream, but you can currently use this branch.